# What's with Luke Cage and coffee?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage-2016

I've seen a lot of memes on the internet about Luke Cage talking about his coffee. For example:

[image: Meme dating "Netflix and Chill" to 2015 and an image of Luke Cage with the caption "Coffee?" dated to 2016]

Also, there's this tweet from official @LukeCage: https://mobile.twitter.com/lukecage/status/786353021756125184?lang=en

> When you ask someone out for coffee and they've seen #LukeCage.

When a guy tweeted:

> I was watching "Luke Cage" last night and my gf said "mm" when he got on screen so looks like we won't be watching that anymore.

@LukeCage replied:

> She like coffee?

What does it mean?

Comment: It corresponds to a running joke in the show. (which I won't details because, well, spoilers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Spoilers throughout.*

In the context of Netflix' Luke Cage (and, bleeding over into Iron Fist),

> Coffee is a euphemism for sex.

In the first episode, after Luke Cage and Misty Knight meet for the first time at the night club.  After they leave and are talking on the sidewalk:

> Misty: You wanna go grab a coffee?
>
> Luke: I don't like coffee.
>
> Misty: Neither do I.
>
> [Music: Chick-a-bow, chick-a-bow-bow...]
>
> [Scene cut: Luke and Misty enter an apartment, undressing each other,
>   and onward to have sex.]

The reference is later made with Claire (without success in S01E06 as @ILoveYou points out, but also later once Claire is ready to have that relationship with Luke).

And soon after Claire is introduced to Danny Rand in Iron Fist, he suggests coffee and she declines in a way that clearly references the subtext coffee had in Luke Cage.

Comment: Shouldn't most of your post be in spoiler tags, EXCEPT the part which actually is in spoiler tags? That euphemism part is the actual and spoilerwise harmless answer. All the rest on the other hand is specific information on what happens throughout the series...

Comment: @xNGTMx my assumption was that anyone who read past the first spoiler tag would understand that there were spoilers - and the first spoiler tag is more for effect than actual spoilage.  A question like this almost can't have an answer without spoilers...

Answer (score 4):

The TV show has done several gags around coffee. One such example is:

In S01E06 *Suckas Need Bodyguards*, Luke invites Claire for a coffee and she replies,

> I am not sleeping with you.

Luke says can't coffee just be coffee, then she replies that she saw him drink orange juice and he didn't even touch his coffee this morning.

Comment: And this is itself a reference to the [_Hot Coffee_ mod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Coffee_mod) from GTA... Now 13 years old.  I think they would've both been teenagers when that game/mod came out.

Comment: @Izkata, it's possible, but I'd be doubtful. The invitation "Wanna come up for coffee?" has been a euphemism for sex for decades, typically when a date is ending and the gentleman has walked the lady to her door, where she chooses to either invite him in (for "coffee", natch) or say goodnight.

Comment: It used to be ["Want to come up and see my etchings?"](https://mic.com/articles/126987/was-this-old-school-meme-the-first-ever-netflix-and-chill#.7rppcjR50) (WARNING - mildly NSFW) from the late 1800's.